# MVC Partial View not returning model on ajax postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view which has a partial view in it, which has a text box in it.  The main view has a model of type person and the partial view a model of type person.other.  When I do a ajax post back the other model is empty, I expected it to pick up the textbox data.  This is the code;

Classes

```
public class Person
    {
        public string PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Other Other { get; set; }
    }

public class Other
    {
        public string OtherName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Other = new Other();

            person.Other.OtherName = "avbc";    

            return View(person);
        }


        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Test(Other other)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("Test");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

View

```
@model PartialViewTest.Models.Person
<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="mydiv">
        @Html.Partial("Test", Model.Other)
</div>
```

PartialView

```
@model PartialViewTest.Models.Other


<h1>Test</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {  id = "testForm" })) { 

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OtherName)

    <input type="submit"/>

}
```

Jquery submit

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#testForm').submit(function () {

        $.post($(this).attr("action"),
             $(this).serialize(),
            function (result) {
                $('#mydiv').html(result);
            });
        );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cancel the default form submission by returning false from the submit callback. Also you seem to be missing a closing `}`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testForm').submit(function () {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (result) {
            $('#mydiv').html(result);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also you might need to modify your controller action like this because what is actually sent to the server is `Other.OtherName=foo`:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Test([Bind(Prefix="Other")]Other other)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made those changes but model is still returning to the action as null.

Comment: @user415394, could you look at what's actually sent with FireBug in the AJAX request? Also checkout my update about using the proper prefix.